# How to set image height in px if the width is a percentage?

Tags: javascript, php, css

If I have set the width of my images to 100% how can I insert the height of the image (in my HTML as height="") as an exact pixel figure? I need the height of all my images so the rest of the page can structure the layout out correctly.

height:auto; is no good because it's as good as leaving height="" empty, it doesn't give any measurement information to the page.

I can grab the exact pixel height of the original image

```
style="height:<?=$image_height[1]?>px;"
```

But once it's been resized by the width it's no longer in proportion, so the original height value is useless as it is.

Is there any solution for this, I'm stumped.

Each image is in a container that is 20% width of the page, making 5 columns.

Comment: I'd suggest attaching a jsfiddle to this question to demonstrate it better if you are unable to find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height (and leave width as auto) as percentage and set the container to a fixed height so your rest layout is fine. Then width of images will adjust accordingly (responsive)

Another solution is to use padding to maintain aspect-ratio of images/videos, if needed i can add this solution as well

Comment: The page is made from 5 columns (20%), with a fixed height the columns wouldn't look neat and parallel. Sorry I don't quite understand, I'm not sure what you mean by using padding as solution

Comment: @GoldenGonaz, then it seems i misunderstood, you mentioned that setting height auto will break the rest layout because height will change, so i suggested this. In the other case just use overflow: hiden in container to hide any extra image height

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css code for setting all images in their actual pixels.

```
img{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me like you need to play around with css property `min-height`

or you may need to dynamically calculate the height of the images with javascript as a proportion of their width , after they have been inserted into the dom.

example:

```
function calculateImageHeight (imageId) {

  var image = document.getElementById(imageId);

  // assuming you want the height to be 50% the width
  return image.width * 0.5;

}
```